# MvvmLight print message to debug

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light

Is there a simple way to print all Messenger.Default.Send() to debug? Don't want to override them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, so i ended up with own wrapper around Messenger. No smart solutions, just straightforward wrapping. In case, anybody else would need it:

```
public static class MvvmLightMessenger
{
    public static void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register(recipient,action);
    }

    public static void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, bool receiveDerivedMessagesToo, Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register(recipient, receiveDerivedMessagesToo, action);
    }

    public static void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, object token, Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register(recipient, token, action);
    }

    public static void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, object token, bool receiveDerivedMessagesToo, Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register(recipient, token, receiveDerivedMessagesToo, action);
    }





    public static void Send<TMessage>(TMessage message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{!} Message: " + message);
        Messenger.Default.Send<TMessage>(message);
    }

    public static void Send<TMessage, TTarget>(TMessage message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{!} Message: " + message + " to target: " + typeof(TTarget));
        Messenger.Default.Send<TMessage, TTarget>(message);
    }

    public static void Send<TMessage>(TMessage message, object token)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{!} Message: " + message + " token: " + token);
        Messenger.Default.Send<TMessage>(message, token);
    }







    public static void Unregister<TMessage>(object recipient)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Unregister<TMessage>(recipient);
    }

    public static void Unregister<TMessage>(object recipient, Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Unregister<TMessage>(recipient, action);
    }

    public static void Unregister<TMessage>(object recipient, object token)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Unregister<TMessage>(recipient, token);
    }

    public static void Unregister<TMessage>(object recipient, object token, Action<TMessage> action)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Unregister<TMessage>(recipient, token, action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in an abstract ViewModel that everyone inherits from, which uses a define or global variable to determine if it debugs as well/instead.  This could also be if you're running as Debug or Release.

```
public abstract BaseViewModel
    public SendMessage()
    {
        if(DEBUG) // The global variable, or definition, or current run type - whatever
            Debug.WriteLine();
        // else // Commented if you want to always send, uncomment if you want to send instead.
        Messenger.Default.Send();
    }


public RealViewModel : BaseViewModel
...
    SomeMethod()
    {
        ...
        base.SendMessage();
```

Comment: Nah, too easy. I already have tons of Send() calls, don't want to change them all to SendMessageWithDebug() or something.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Then you'd need to override or include and change source, which seemed against your statement in the original post.

Comment: Maybe some kind of extension? Maybe i wasnt that clear in original statement. I mean, i'm looking for a smart way, which would allow me to do minimal amount of changes.