# MVVMLight Message Logging

Tags: .net, logging, message, mvvm-light, messenger

I want to log all messages that are sended via the MVVMLight default messenger.
For this i need a wrapper class [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301887/mvvmlight-print-message-to-debug), that writes informations about the sender and recipient to the debug output.

The following wrapper class successfully logs sended message and the name of the sender to the debug.
However it does not log receiving a message properly:
When a message is sended, the recipient is logged once. 
When the same message is sended again, the recipient will not receive the message.

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging

Public Class MonitoringMessenger

    Public Shared Sub Send(Of TMessage)(message As TMessage, sender As Object)

        Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetType.Name & "(" & sender.GetHashCode() & ") sended " & GetType(TMessage).Name)
        Messenger.Default.Send(Of TMessage)(message)

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Register(Of TMessage)(ByVal recipient As Object, action As Action(Of TMessage))

        Dim monitoredAction As Action(Of TMessage) = Sub(msg As TMessage)
                                                         action.Invoke(msg)
                                                         Debug.WriteLine(recipient.GetType.Name & "(" & recipient.GetHashCode() & ") received " & GetType(TMessage).Name)
                                                     End Sub

        Messenger.Default.Register(Of TMessage)(recipient, monitoredAction)

    End Sub

End Class
```

And i call it just like the real mvvm light messenger:

```
MonitoringMessenger.Register(Of TextMessage)(Me, AddressOf OnTextMessageReceived)
```

And sending:

```
MonitoringMessenger.Send(Of TextMessage)(New TextMessage(Me.InputTextBox.Text), Me)
```

So my question is, what is wrong with my generic code? 
Why is a message received once and then never again?

I already tested a non-generic version and it worked right. 
But that is inconvenient since i have a lot of message types.

**EDIT:**
I experienced, that when I don't reference any variable inside the monitoredAction inline-delegate, then it works.

So this works:

```
Public Shared Sub Register(Of TMessage)(ByVal recipient As Object, action As Action(Of TMessage))

        Dim monitoredAction As Action(Of TMessage) = Sub(msg As TMessage)
                                                         Debug.WriteLine("monitoredAction called")
                                                     End Sub

        Messenger.Default.Register(Of TMessage)(recipient, monitoredAction)

    End Sub
```

How can I access the variables ***action*** and ***recipient*** without changing the signature of the delegate (*Sub(msg As TMessage)*)?